# How do I group by then filter without losing rows from data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample `tbl_df` that I am trying to find a solution to.  I am trying to do the following at a high level.  Compare the max score for a student in 2021 (based on which type count they have the most of) to their most recent result in that `type` in the most recent year before 2021.  I'd like to use `dplyr::filter` but can't figure out how to `filter` properly to retain the `tbl_df` to get to my output.

In brief:

1. Group by `full_name` and choose the `type` row that has the `max` value in the `count` column for 2021
2. Choose the next most recent year for that same `type`

As you can see, since Eric Collins doesn't have a row in 2020, his most recent year is 2019, while the others have values in 2020.

Sample:

```
sample_df <- tibble::tribble(
                  ~year,           ~full_name,        ~type, ~count, ~avg_score, ~max,
                  2021L,       "Jason Valdez",   "Sciences",   "33",         98,   99,
                  2021L,       "Jason Valdez", "Humanities",   "59",         97,   99,
                  2020L,       "Jason Valdez",   "Sciences",  "164",         97,   99,
                  2020L,       "Jason Valdez", "Humanities",  "231",         96,   98,
                  2019L,       "Jason Valdez",   "Sciences",  "933",         96,   99,
                  2019L,       "Jason Valdez", "Humanities",  "853",         95,   99,
                  2021L,       "Eric Collins",   "Sciences",   "21",         92,   93,
                  2019L,       "Eric Collins",   "Sciences",  "831",         94,   97,
                  2019L,       "Eric Collins", "Humanities",   "10",         94,   97,
                  2021L, "Sebastian Goldberg",   "Sciences",   "41",         93,   96,
                  2020L, "Sebastian Goldberg",   "Sciences",  "476",         94,   98,
                  2020L, "Sebastian Goldberg", "Humanities",   "81",         93,   96,
                  2019L, "Sebastian Goldberg",   "Sciences", "1418",         95,   98
                  )

output_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year,           ~full_name,        ~type, ~count, ~avg_score, ~max,
  2021L,       "Jason Valdez", "Humanities",    59L,        95L,  96L,
  2020L,       "Jason Valdez", "Humanities",   231L,        96L,  98L,
  2021L,       "Eric Collins",   "Sciences",    21L,        92L,  93L,
  2019L,       "Eric Collins",   "Sciences",   831L,        94L,  97L,
  2021L, "Sebastian Goldberg",   "Sciences",    41L,        93L,  96L,
  2020L, "Sebastian Goldberg",   "Sciences",   476L,        94L,  98L
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by 'full_name', `filter` the 'type' based on the 'type' that corresponds to the `max` `count` value where 'year' is 2021 and then `slice` the max 2 rows ordered by 'year'

```
library(dplyr)
sample_df %>% 
   group_by(full_name) %>% 
   filter(type %in% type[which.max(count[year == 2021])])%>% 
   slice_max(order_by= year, n = 2) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(factor(full_name, levels = unique(sample_df$full_name)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#   year full_name          type       count avg_score   max
#  <int> <chr>              <chr>      <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2021 Jason Valdez       Humanities 59           97    99
#2  2020 Jason Valdez       Humanities 231          96    98
#3  2021 Eric Collins       Sciences   21           92    93
#4  2019 Eric Collins       Sciences   831          94    97
#5  2021 Sebastian Goldberg Sciences   41           93    96
#6  2020 Sebastian Goldberg Sciences   476          94    98
```

Comment: Perfect.  So does the [ ] within the filter allow you to create a filter subset without removing the rows the same way a traditional filter would work?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you akrun!

Comment: @Jazzmatazz It is just to make sure that we don't lose that entire row. i.e. suppose we do `filter(year == 2021)` then we may need to `merge` later the subset data

Comment: Yep.  That's what I was asking.  Thanks!  I didn't know you could do that within filter.  What is the arrange/factor at the bottom for?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz it is just to arrange the ouptut as in the original order.  It can be removed and used in `group_by(full_name = factor(full_name, levels = unique(full_name)))`, otherwise, it orders the rows by the alphabetic order instead of the order of occurence of unique names